# How to turn a float into a list. (Python)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I need to turn a float into a list. (Python 2.7.10)
Eg.

```
float = 7.434

list = [7, ".", 4, 3, 4]
```

I need this so I can iterate the float.

Comment: `list(int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in str(float))` if you don't care about precision

Comment: What do you mean by "iterate the float"?  Why do you think you need to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *have* to have a list:

```
list(int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in str(7.345))
```

but you can iterate over a string

```
for i in str(-7.345): print i
-
7
.
3
4
5
```

(note that all of these would be strings...)

Comment: There's really nothing wrong with this *answer*, but I'm curious as to why one would want to do this in the first place...

Comment: There are a number of project euler questions where you have to do something based on, say, the sum of the digits to a number. Granted, at least 70% of the time, you should strongly consider using a `Counter` instead and rethinking your solution, but it's a thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
[int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in map(str, str(number))]
```

Example:

```
>>> num = 1.2345
>>> [int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in map(str, str(num))]
[1, '.', 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> num = -1.2345
>>> [int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in map(str, str(num))]
['-', 1, '.', 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `list = list(str(float))`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is usefull :D

```
#You have a float like this :` float = 7.434`
#Now ,  let's convert the "float" variable to a list:

float=7.434
LIST=[]
float_to_str=str(float)
for elem in float_to_str:
    #In elem is a dot ( . ) :
    if elem==".":
        LIST.append(elem)
    else:
        #If the element is a number:
        LIST.append( int(elem) )



#    In case you want to see you list : 
print(str(LIST))

#GOOD LUCK :D 
#WATERFULL IDR  is planning to earn money with python , if you want to join me making and 
#selling games , don't hesitate : facebook : Waterfull Idr ------- GOOD LUCK ----------
#;D
```